# Fourier transform of Dirac delta distribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f,g$ be Schwartz functions on $\mathbb R^4$, we denote them as $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^4)$, one can then define the transform $V$ mapping $f,g$ to a Schwartz function $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^8)$
$$ V(f,g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{2\pi i x_1 y} f(y+\tfrac{x_2}{2})\overline{g(y-\tfrac{x_2}{2})} \ dy.$$

I wonder if one find a map $G:\mathcal S(\mathbb R^8) \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$G(V(f,g)) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(t,t)\overline{g(t,t)} \ dt.$$

Of course this just means that $G(V(f,g))=\delta(t_1-t_2)MV^{-1}V(f,g),$
where $M(f,g)=f\overline{g}$ and $\delta(t_1-t_2)h := \int_{\mathbb R^2} h(t,t) \ dt.$

So this is fine, but I wonder if one could find at least a formal integral representation of this map $G$, i.e. does there exist a kernel $G(x)$ such that

$$GV(f,g) = \int_{\mathbb R^8} G(x) V(f,g)(x) \ dx?$$